# Secure container for Android Tablet user

Tags: samsung, multi-user, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I've got an Android tablet that has multi-user support. Galaxy Tab 3 if I remember correctly.

Now, I'd like to store some of my files on it but so that apps and I could access it on my user, but not other users or their apps on that tablet. It must only be accessible if my user is unlocked on the tablet, if I lock the screen it should stop being accessible.

Comment: Isn't that how multi-user works? It's not really clear what you're asking. Have you tried using mult-user? If so, why is that not suitable? Also, please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details) if that is what you're after.

Comment: @bmdixon No idea, googling did not help at all.  Yes,  I am using it. It is not entirely suitable? The question is where/how do I store data so that my apps like Gallery or Music etc. can access and find it but not so that other users on that tablet can do the same.

Comment: I *think* that each user gets a separate storage location (internal storage that appears as /sdcard) so any files that you store will not be accessible to other users. All apps are separate too so their data is not shared. Why do you say that it's not suitable? Have you verified that the files are accessible to another user? I don't use multi-user myself so i could be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203257) the storage should be separated.

Each user gets their own space on the emulated storage which other users cannot access to read or write (assuming the device is not rooted, in which case all of this goes out the window...).

As far as installed apps are concerned, the fact that there are several installations of it on one device is indistinguishable from being installed on several devices. So each user can access the app as though they are the user of the device.

Therefore you should be able to store files on the 'sdcard' (internal storage) and they will not be accessible to other users of the device. Assuming your user has a lock screen PIN/Password/pattern/etc. then they will not be able to access the files unless you unlock the device and 'log in' as your user.